# How to change folder view in Finder

Tags: finder, macos

Is it possible to change the way folder content is organised to show in vertical columns?

When viewing content by icon macOS Sierra seems to automatically sort in vertical rows from left to right. There don't seem to any options to change this in 'View Options'. Organising content vertically seems particularly confusing when viewing larger number of files.

current: [image: content organised horizontally]
desired: [image: content organised vertically]

Comment: I don't have Sierra to test - but Cmd/1, 2, 3, 4 should change from Icon to list to column to coverflow views. Or View menu. Cmd/J should give you settings you can then save as defaults.

Comment: To clarify, this is to change the way content is organised in Icon view instead of switching the view altogether.

Comment: ah, OK - sorry, I've no idea. I actually never use icon view, I had assumed you meant column, but afaik, Mac has always sorted icons left to right.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I currently know how to do this is to change the icons so that they are bigger. You will not, however, get the files in two columns.

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
2. Set the "icon size"" setting to use large icons